# Does anyone know how to display a BitmapField?

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

I have a code that encode a image to bitmap. But I am not sure on how to display it on the screen. By the way, I am using Blackberry JavaME. This is the code where i use to encode the image. Is this the way I can use in order to get image from a sd card and display it on the screen?

```
FileConnection conn = 
    (FileConnection)Connector.open("image1.png",Connector.READ_WRITE);
if(conn.exists()) {
    InputStream is = conn.openInputStream();
    BitmapField bitmap = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int ch;
    while ((ch = is.read()) != -1)
    {
        baos.write(ch);
    }
    byte imageData[] = baos.toByteArray();
    bitmap = new BitmapField(
        EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(imageData, 0, imageData.length).getBitmap());
    add(bitmap);
}
```

Comment: Here are some things that come to my mind from looking at that code:  I assume "image1.png" is just a placeholder for an actual URI e.g. "file:///store/home/pictures/image1.png"; if the Bitmap is packaged in with the app then use Bitmap.getBitmapResource and if it's on the file system then use a FileConnection but with a real path.  If you add another field right after you add the bitmap can you see that field?  Are you sure the image is a valid bitmap?  You could use Bitmap.createBitmapFromBytes() rather than the method in EncodedImage and save some space.

Comment: How do I add a real path in the fileconnection? Will this work ?FileConnection conn = (FileConnection)Connector.open("file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/documents/" + "image1.png",Connector.READ_WRITE);

Comment: That looks like a valid path, now just make sure there's an image there.  And you don't need to use READ_WRITE since you just want to read the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Secko is correct that you can override paint but I think you are getting stuck because you have not created a ui application.

Here is a very simple ui application example for displaying a bitmap field, if you copy it exactly you will need an images folder under src with image.png inside of it.

This was modified from the HelloWorldDemo that comes with the SDK. I recommend that if you are just starting out you look at the samples in the folder. 
\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack5.0.0_5.0.0.25\components\samples\

good luck

Ray

```
public class DisplayBitmaps extends UiApplication
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DisplayBitmaps theApp = new DisplayBitmaps();       
        theApp.enterEventDispatcher();
    }

    public DisplayBitmaps()
    {        
        pushScreen(new DisplayBitmapsScreen());
    }    
}

final class DisplayBitmapsScreen extends MainScreen
{
    DisplayBitmapsScreen()
    {    
     Bitmap bitmap = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("images/image.png").getBitmap();
     BitmapField bitmapField = new BitmapField(bitmap);
        add(bitmapField);
    }

    public void close()
    {  
        super.close();
    }   
}
```

Edit for when the image is on the sdcard

```
DisplayBitmapsScreen()
{    
 //Bitmap bitmap = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("images/image.png").getBitmap();
 try {
  FileConnection fc = (FileConnection) Connector.open("file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/pictures/image.png");
  if (fc.exists()) {
   byte[] image = new byte[(int) fc.fileSize()];
   InputStream inStream = fc.openInputStream();
   inStream.read(image);
   inStream.close();
   EncodedImage encodedImage = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(image, 0, -1);
   BitmapField bitmapField = new BitmapField(encodedImage.getBitmap());
   fc.close();
   add(bitmapField);
  }
 } catch (Exception e) { System.out.println("EXCEPTION " + e); }
}
```

Overriding paint in Field or any extension Field class could also display an image, but I didn't really understand from Secko's example where he would display the image so I have included drawImage in this example below.

```
protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
   graphics.drawImage(x, y, width, height, image, frameIndex, left, top);
   super.paint(graphics);
}
```

Comment: Does this work if I am tryin to get the image from a sd card?

Comment: I've added an example for when the image is on the sdcard. One quirk with the simulator is detecting the sdcard, you may notice when you run the app the first time the image doesn't load but the second time it does. For this I recommend looking at http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/1295814/How_To_-_Programmatically_determine_if_a_microSD_card_has_been_inserted.html?nodeid=1295868&vernum=0

Comment: when i get to this part bitmap = image.getBitmap();     it will throw me a Uncaught: IllegalArgumentException. Why is it so?

Comment: I assume the code you have pasted is a reference my example above in which case image is a byte[] and not an EncodedImage that you can .getBitmap from. EncodedImage encodedImage = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(image, 0, -1);
            BitmapField bitmapField = new BitmapField(encodedImage.getBitmap());

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with:

> paint(Graphics g);

Perhaps in a function:

```
protected void DrawStuff(Graphics g) {              
    this.paint(g);
}
```